# How to check if the mouse is pressed out of an JFrame

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe, mouse-listeners

Right now I am using a MouseListener to see if the mouse is pressed but it doesn't register when you press outside of an JFrame I would really need it to so how do I check for mouse events outside of a JFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right now I am using a MouseListener to see if the mouse is pressed
>   but it doesn't register when you press outside of an JFrame I would
>   really need it to so how do I check for mouse events outside of a
>   JFrame?

- then `JFrame` lost `Focus`, you can test by using [WindowFocusListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowFocusListener.html)
- Focus is asynchronous, then everything inside `windowGainedFocus` and `windowLostFocus` should be wrapped into `invokeLater`

Comment: Thank you I forgot about the lost focus. It wasn't really what I asked for but does what I intended to and will probably be easier then anything other.

Answer (score 0):

Add a window listener

```
addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {


        }
    });
```

Try out all the methods (window...) and see which one works out best for you!
:)
I'm not telling you exactly what to do because to learn you cant just copy paste!

Comment: That's the second time you've suggested that an op add a MouseListener to their application, even though both times it was stated they were already using one...

Answer (score 0):

To know the status of mouse outside the window you can use:

```
Point point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
```

Unfortunatly `java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener` give you information about mouse movement inside your window.

Comment: I want to know if the mouse is pressed not where it is but thanks anyway.